# Can i change input value populated from component state from console

Tags: reactjs

Can i change input value populated from component state from console by using something like `document.getElementById('someId').value="some_value"` in react

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: I want to automated some test script so that i dont need to fill input values manually instead populate them from script.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Whatever the Library/Framework you are using to build your DOM, it will eventually produce DOM, thus, it will be available and accessed as: `window`, `document` and everything inside of them.

So, doing the following will update value of the field that matches with the parameter given to the `getElementById`.

```
document.getElementById('someId').value="some_value"
```

Comment: Yes, but thats only updating  the value in UI ie update value of input field. When i debug that in React dev tool state value is not updated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use React Developer Tools to trace and edit value of state

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Hope this help!

Comment: I want to fill input values from script in console so that i dont need to manually enter all input fields and can automate some testing.